# JMeter For-Each Controller - Seems to Run Only First Several Iterations, Then Stops

Tags: loops, foreach, jmeter

Here are UDVs, which I use as loop variables:
[image: Loop Variables]

Here is the For-Each definition.
[image: for-each panel]

When I run this from starting = 1 to ending = 11, it only runs 1, 2, 3, 4.
Then it stops.
Here is loop #4.
[image: Working HTTP request]

This shows that variable status_1, status_2, ... , status_11 are all defined.
[image: JMeter debug output, showing all variables]

The question is: why is status_5 and onwards not running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you made a typo/copy paste issue and one of the variables have an extra non-printable character like [whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) or [line break](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)

Or there is something else preventing the test from execution like [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) which has run out of the values or error has occurred and [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) is configured to stop in that case of whatever.

Check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries, if nothing unusual is there - [increase JMeter logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) and check it again.

Under normal circumstances the ForEach Controller works as expected:

[image]

Comment: Exactly as you suspected.  Extra space *only* for #5.   All the rest were fine.  So I guess that broke the cycle